# Клиент+сервер ассинхронные сокеты + await async

Tags: c#, сокеты, async-await

Есть клиент и сервер основанные на ассинхронных сокетах и ключевых словах `await` и `async`. Проблема следующая я хочу передать картинку от сервера клиенту. Логика такая `bitmap->byte[]->char[]` и передаю `char[]` массив ну и на стороне клиента обратно декодирую. Вопрос следующий не могу понять почему при декодировании и итоге часть данных масива "теряется" т.е вручную глянул эл-ты передаваемого и принятого массива и значения в конце массива различны.
Собственно код:
**Сервер**:

```
             CodingImage img = new CodingImage();
             buffer = img.CodingImages("C:\\image\\lol.bmp");
             bufferChar = Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(buffer);
             char lastindex = bufferChar[218726];
             count = bufferChar.Length;
             lenght = bufferChar.Length.ToString();
             var tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
             HandleConnectionAsync(tcpClient);


private async void
HandleConnectionAsync(TcpClient tcpClient)
         {
             string clientInfo = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
             LogMessage(string.Format("Gotconnection request from {0}", clientInfo));
             try
             {
                 using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                 using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
                 using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
                 {
                     writer.AutoFlush = true;
                     while (true)
                     {
                         //var dataFromServer = await
 reader.ReadAsync(bufferChar, 0, count);
                         /*if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataFromServer.ToString()))
                         {
                             break;
                         }
                         LogMessage(dataFromServer.ToString());
                          */
                         await writer.WriteLineAsync(lenght);
                         await writer.WriteAsync(bufferChar, 0, count);
                     }
                 }
             }



 public byte[] CodingImages(string path)
         {
             Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(path);
             TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
             byte[] MassOfPicture = (byte[])tc.ConvertTo(picture, typeof(byte[]));
             byte lastindex = MassOfPicture[437453];
             return MassOfPicture;
         }
```

**Клиент**:

```
 TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
             await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, port);
             LogMessage("Connected to Server");
             using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
             using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
             using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream)) 
             {
                 writer.AutoFlush = true;
                 for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                 {
                     //await writer.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                     var lenght = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                     int lenghtInt = Convert.ToInt32(lenght.ToString());
                     recievedChar = new char[lenghtInt];
                     await reader.ReadAsync(recievedChar, 0, lenghtInt);
                     char lastindex = recievedChar[218726];
                     EncodingImage img = new EncodingImage();
                     img.EncodingImages(recievedChar);

                     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lenght))
                     {
                         LogMessage(lenght);
                     }

                 }
             }

 public void EncodingImages(char[] recievedChar)
         {
             byte[] recieved = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(recievedChar);
             byte lastindex = recieved[437453];
             TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
             Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(recieved);
             bitmap.Save("C:\\image\\lol_recieved.bmp");
         }
```

Ну а сами различия заметны в переменных "lastindex"
Собственно может объяснить кто нибудь в чем может быть проблема?
Мне ещё не очень нравиться вся эта цепочка кодирования и декодирования. Но делал ее из-за методов `WriteAsync` и `ReadAsync` они принимают `char[]`.

Comment: А зачем вам переходить от `byte[]` к `char[]`? Передавайте и принимайте массивы байт, так правильнее как-то.

Вам совершенно не нужно надевать дополнительные `StreamReader` и `StreamWriter`, у `NetworkStream`, который вы получаете от `TcpClient`'а, есть метод `ReadAsync(byte[], ...)`[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh193669].

Comment: Кроме того, не забывайте, что данные вам передаются не целиком, а кусками. Так что вам надо в цикле вычитывать куски данных, и складировать их в буфере, пока не достигнете необходимой длины.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку с NetworkStream. Да, что то не подумал.
"Так что вам надо в цикле вычитывать куски данных, и складировать их в буфере, пока не достигнете необходимой длины."
Хмм а можно какой-нибудь минимальный пример. Ну или на словах, не очень понял почему нельзя передать целый массив байт так, как я сделал.

Comment: @Игорь Васильев: передать-то можно, но придёт всё равно кусками. Вот, например, объяснение: <http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html>. А вот и пример кода: <http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html>. (Автор в начало сообщения кладёт его длину, так что принимающий код знает, сколько данных ему ожидать.)

---
Кстати, заметьте, что с async/await читать данные кусками намного проще, чем в примере автора: вы можете держать все переменный локально:

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите, как можно сделать:

```
async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync(NetworkStream s, int nbytes)
{
    var buf = new byte[nbytes];
    var readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nbytes)
        readpos += await s.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos);
    return buf;
}
```

Если вы знаете длину сообщения заранее, вы просто можете использовать эту процедуру. Если вы будете передавать в начале потока длину, как в статье по ссылке из комментария, делайте так:

```
var lengthBuffer = await ReadFromStreamAsync(s, 4);
var nbytes = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);
var data = await ReadFromStreamAsync(s, nbytes);
```

Видите, насколько проще с async/await?

Comment: Хорошо, как сделать ясно. Но у меня все равно вопрос "а зачем это делать", просто я сейчас, как вы подсказали, спокойно передал массив байт и все успешно декодировалось. Я все это к тому, что хочу понять зачем делать такую махинацию, что мы выйграем если будем так делать. Так будет быстрее?

Comment: @Игорь Васильев: Ну вы всё же прочитайте текст по ссылке. Протокол TCP **не гарантирует**, что посланные одним куском данные дойдут тоже одним куском.