# Асинхронные сокеты, объясните логику

Tags: c#, сокет

Вот пример `ReceiveCallback` из MSDN.

```
int bytesRecv = clientSocket.EndReceive(result);

if (bytesRecv > 0)
{
    clientSocket.BeginReceive(ci.Buffer, 0, ci.Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), ci);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Response");
}
```

Допустим размер буфера на стороне клиента 16 байт. Если я отправляю со стороны сервера допустим 32 байта, то callback отрабатывает только два раза приняв 16 + 16 байт. В связи с этим не работает проверка `bytesRecv = 0`, и `Console.WriteLine("")` не отрабатывает, т.к. третий раз callback не запускается. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А почему вы пользуетесь устаревшим BeginReceive/EndReceive? Почему не async?

Comment: И количество принятых байт определяется не (только) размером буфера у клиента, а ещё миллионом факторов по дороге между ними.

Comment: устаревшими функциями пользуюсь т.к. касательно сокетам в интернете нашел только упоминание про них. async это я понимаю применимо вообще к асинхронным функциям? Просто не доводилось использовать. Буду копать в этом направлении.

Comment: Вот тут есть немного по теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/418010/10105

Comment: Спасибо большое, что указали правильный путь. Буду разбираться в новом подходе :)

Comment: И вот ещё: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/306562/10105

Comment: Да, я разобрался с async/await мне в общем то понравился такой подход, еще раз спасибо. Но я опять пришел к тому, что когда я читаю из потока данные, в момент когда поток полностью прочитан, ReceiveAsync должна выдать длину принятого пакета равную нулю(то что читать больше нечего), что-бы отследить окончание приема, но у меня тупо виснет цикл на этой функции, т.к. функция не возвращает ничего. Я вот и понять не могу что ни так у меня. Пока использую костыль в виде bytesRecv > buffer.Lenght.

Comment: Ну, тут вот что. ReadAsync хочет вернуть хотя бы один байт, и если не происходит ошибки, ждёт, пока этот байт не придёт. Если вы знаете, что будет отправлено 32 байта, то вы должны просто читать, пока не придут все 32 байта.

Comment: ReadAsync не знает, что данных больше не будет, и никак не может узнать, если вы ему не скажете. Поэтому при передаче данных через сокет вы должны сами изобрести протокол, в котором вы будете сначала сообщать длину сообщения, а потом передавать само сообщение.

Comment: Ну все теперь понятно. Все к этому и шло :) Просто тогда не понятно, как в примерах из MSDN такой подход работает. И самое главное, что когда я впервые пробовал асинхронные сокеты, он работал :) Поэтому я в недоумении. Чтож будем собирать протокол. Если возникнут вопросы, буду рад вашей помощи :)

Comment: Ну, работает всё, если пересылать между машинами в одной подсети. А если по пути есть раутинг, то включается в игру размер пакета на промежуточных машинах :-\

Comment: Обращайтесь, поможем!

Comment: Короче я вам честно скажу, я в восторге от async/await :) Век живи, век учись! :)

Comment: async/await превращают асинхронное программирование в детскую игру. это пожалуй самое крутое, что случилось в мейнстримном программировании за последние 5 лет.

Answer (score 2):

Пример на MSDN подразумевает, что после отправки данных другая сторона закроет исходящий поток:

```
socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
```

В таком случае получатель при попытке чтения прочитает ноль байт из сокета.

Подобный режим работы - "послать данные, закрыть исходящий поток, принять данные" - является самым простым для протокола TCP и исторически первым использовавшимся. Поэтому большинство примеров работы с сокетами написаны под подобный протокол.

Если вам надо держать соединение установленным - то вам надо придумать свой способ определения границ сообщения. Это может быть либо особый маркер окончания сообщения, либо явная пересылка длины перед самим сообщением.

Для примера, протокол HTTP использует комбинированный подход - блок заголовков заканчивается двумя переводами строки, а блок данных (называемый в протоколе HTTP *тело содержимого*) имеет длину ровно `Content-Length` байт. Если же заголовок `Content-Length` не указан - блок данных заканчивается закрытием сокета.

Answer (score 1):

В третий раз он продолжает ждать данные от клиента. Откуда ему знать сколько данных вы ему отправили. Условие

```
if (bytesRecv > 0) ... else ...
```

сработает, если прервется связь с клиентом.

Answer (score 1):

См. [в другом ответе пример клиент-серверного взаимодействия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516728/192004). Там каждый клиент получает ответ от сервера, а потом выводит на консоль. Причем реализация такова, что после получения символа конца строки `\n` клиент перестает уже принимать данные.

Как я понял, вам надо примерно то же самое, но вместо вывода на консоль необходимо накапливать данные, а потому уже что-то с ними делать.

Можно передавать в самом начале длину, а потом ждать до тех пор, пока не придут все символы (длину мы знаем). Таким образом можно избавиться от спецсимвола.